# Error when using customized port in redirect_uri in google oauth2.0

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

Whenever I use a customize port in the redirect uris, google will redirect me to an error page saying "OpenID 2.0 for Google Accounts has gone away", try to click the link below to recreate this issue

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login&state=kkk&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fcheckauth&response_type=code&client_id=247142348909-2s8tudf2n69iedmt4tvt2bun5bu2ro5t.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force

But when I delete the port from the callback url, google can redirect to the specified redirect uri.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login&state=kkk&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fcheckauth&response_type=code&client_id=247142348909-2s8tudf2n69iedmt4tvt2bun5bu2ro5t.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force

The two urls are exactly the same except the second one does not have ":3000" in the redirect_uri parameter. Is there something i miss here?

---

In May 5th, both links can successfully redirect to the specified URLs, **problem solved**

Comment: have you included the URL with the port in the list of redirect URLs in the Google API Console?

Comment: according to the documents, I don't need to include the port. I included the URL with the port once, it did not work either. And the error page is not about illegal URL

Comment: Not sure what docs you're reading. The URL must be a character for character match or it will fail.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi  "You may specify a port number without changing the Google Developers Console configuration. "  Even I include port in the URL in API console, it still fails, besides the error is not "invalid redirect URI"

Comment: From the same page "The value of this parameter must exactly match one of the values that appear in the Credentials page in the Google Developers Console (including the http or https scheme, case, and trailing slash)."

Comment: Is it this that you're seeing "OpenID 2.0 for Google Accounts has gone away... OpenID 2.0 was replaced by OpenID Connect, and since April 20, 2015, no longer works for Google Accounts..."

Comment: I tried to add the port in the API console, it did not work. Yes, for the first URL I get "OpenID 2.0 for Google Accounts has gone away... ", for the second URL, everything is fine.

Comment: Do you get "since April 20, 2015, no longer works for Google Accounts."????

Comment: Hey, both links work now! I did not change a thing. They must fixed something. Thank you @pinoyyid for answering my question.